# Spy dataLayer from Google Analytics with Puppeteer and Mocha / Sinon (or similar)

Tags: google-analytics, mocha.js, sinon, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

So, I am trying to make automatic tests on my Google Analytics calls with Headless Chromes + Puppeteer + Mocha + Sinon but can't manage to read the dataLayer value for Sinon to spy.

This is what I have so far. But window is always undefined.
test is a class to proxy pass puppeteer calls to the inner browser.

```
const { test } = require('../browser');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const dataLayerName = 'dataLayer';

const assert = sinon.assert;

describe('Tests Analytics', () => {
    let spy;

    it('find home analytics', test(async (browser, opts) => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(`${opts.appUrl}`);

        spy = sinon.spy(window.dataLayer, 'push');
        assert.called(spy);
        assert.calledWith(spy, [
          'fail for me',
        ]);
        spy.restore();
    }));
});
```

This is the Browser class:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

/**
 * This is a thin wrapper so that we use a singleton of
 * the browser that puppeteer creates
 */
class Browser {
  setUp(done) {
    const puppeteerOpts = this.options && this.options.puppeteer ?
      this.options.puppeteer :
      {};

    puppeteer.launch(puppeteerOpts).then(async (b) => {
      this.setBrowser(b);
      done();
    });
  }

  setBrowser(b) {
    this.browser = b;
    const oldNewPage = this.browser.newPage.bind(this.browser);

    this.browser.newPage = async function () {
      const page = await oldNewPage();
      this.lastPage = page;

      return page;
    };
  }

  setOptions(opts) {
    this.options = opts;
  }

  test(promise) {
    return (done) => {
      promise(this.browser, this.options)
        .then(() => done()).catch(done);
    };
  }
}

/*
 * Create a new browser and use a proxy to pass
 * any puppeteer calls to the inner browser
 */
module.exports = new Proxy(new Browser(), {
  get(target, name) {
    return name in target ? target[name].bind(target) : target.browser[name];
  },
});
```

Comment: Looking at the doc, It seems impossible, as you can expose functions from node to the page context, in that direction only https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction Still, I am also interested in a solution

Comment: You can access dataLayer using page.evaluate('dataLayer'), that shoudl return a javascript array. Ex: const dl = await page.evaluate('dataLayer'); console.log('dl: ', dl); As to know if you can watch it, I guess you could just get the dataLayer value before each test (like onbeforerequest) and test on it ?

Answer (score 3):

This worked out for me:

```
let datalayer = await page.evaluate('dataLayer');
console.log(datalayer);
```